# Why couldn't I install Skype before running `sudo apt update`?

Tags: software-installation

I tried to install Skype on my PC, but it did not get installed. My friend ran the `sudo apt update` command. After the command had run he installed Skype. Then the installation ran easily.

So my question is, why wouldn't the installation run before running the command `sudo apt update`?

Comment: When you ran the install for skype, did it say that it couldn't find the package?  If it idd, that's because the system didn't know what packages were available from the repositories.  It only knows that information after an `apt update`.

Comment: Thomhttps://askubuntu.com/users/10616/thomas-wardas Ward it did not say anything else but it remains on the same window where it was after clicking install